# How to play two videos side-by-side synchronously when they have different length?

Tags: windows-7, video, sync, vlc-media-player, media-player

Before going into the question, let's review what we have gotten on "[How to play multiple videos side-by-side synchronized?](http://How%20to%20play%20multiple%20videos%20side-by-side%20synchronized?)".

But the answer there supposed that the video files themselves were already synchronized to each other. Then what we need to do is merely to play them together with a central control to pause, forward and backward.

But what if the video files are not synchronized to each other such that we may need to delay some of the files for a few seconds in order to achieve the synchronous effect.

For my question, I'm only concerned on playing two video files. So does anyone know if it is possible to do this?